# I can't get my app to ask for BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth

I am trying to add a "Scan available bluetooth devices" to my app. My app is running on devices with Android 7 or higher.

Till now, what I've found is that I must use the function `startDiscovery()` which makes use of the permission `BLUETOOTH_SCAN`. But for some reason, I can't get the dialog to show up for that permission and `onRequestPermissionsResult()` gives me grantResults = [-1] (i.e. not `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`). I've been looking for several hours now why could be my issue but still no luck.

What I've tried:

- I've tested other permissions just to see if for some reason none of the permissions worked --> All other permissions (CAMERA, STORAGE,...) show the dialog if they are not already granted
- I've checked if for some reason there is a bluetooth permission denied on my device's settings page --> Apparently there isn't
- I've added a check to the following permissions because I read it might be related --> `BLUETOOTH`, `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` (They are all granted on my app as of right now)
- I've added a strong assertion that location is never used (yes, even if I added the permission) because I don't need it, I just want to scan available bluetooth devices --> `android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"`

None of the above worked, dialog does not appear and permission is "by default" denied.

Here is an extract of my code:
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
...
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;
    private static final int BT1_PERMISSION_CODE = 1001;
    private static final int BT2_PERMISSION_CODE = 1002;
    private static final int BT3_PERMISSION_CODE = 1003;
    private static final int BT4_PERMISSION_CODE = 1004;
    private static final int BT5_PERMISSION_CODE = 1005;
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bluetooth1 = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth1);
        bluetooth2 = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth2);
        bluetooth3 = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth3);
        bluetooth4 = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth4);
        bluetooth5 = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth5);
        camera = findViewById(R.id.camera);

        // Set Buttons on Click Listeners
        bluetooth1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, BT1_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        });
        bluetooth2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, BT2_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        });
        bluetooth3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, BT3_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        });
        bluetooth4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, BT4_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        });
        bluetooth5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BT5_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        });

        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        });

    }
...
 public void checkPermission(String permission, int requestCode)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            // Requesting the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
...
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
                permissions,
                grantResults);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Camera Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Camera Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == BT1_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT1 Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT1 Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == BT2_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT2 Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT2 Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == BT3_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT3 Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT3 Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == BT4_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT4 Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT4 Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == BT5_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT5 Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT5 Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Well, as of right now, when I ask for `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` I automatically get a Toast saying "BT5 Permission Denied" but I did not get the opportunity to grant it.

Hope someone is able to give me a hint on what could be my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of checking, I did not manage to display any dialog box. Strangely enough, I did manage to get `startDiscovery()` to work.

For some reason I don't understand, `startDiscovery()` makes use of the permission `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` which should be granted by the user, and since no dialog box appears, permission is indeed "denied". But just by using the `requestPermissions()` method, IDE does not complain and discovery is made.

What is true is that location permissions need to be granted, and both `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` must be declared in the manifest.

I don't understand it, but it works, so I'm not gonna complain about it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey! I have the same issue as you did at the moment (a.k.a all permissions declared in the manifest, and requested at runtime by the activity using `requestPermissions`) yet I also do not get `PERMISSION_GRANTED` when the `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback is called. Would you mind explicitly stating what fixed it for you ?

Comment: The thing is that I did not do anything in particular. I just noticed that I had to request the permission using requestPermissions(), but for some extraordinary and weird reason, it is not mandatory to grant it. So, once I added the requestPermissions() and requested bt, location etc. the only dialog that appeared was the one related to location. Once location is granted, it just works. If someone has an explanation for this, please, be my guest

Comment: @P.Frau What version of Android is your test device running? If it is Android 11 or lower, you won't need BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission to be granted for it to work.

Comment: Apparently, that might be the reason why the popup does not appear

Comment: From what I can gather (been working with this the last few days), the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission doesn't exist for devices on Android version < 12, so you'll never get `PERMISSION_GRANTED`, so it's useless to ask if you have that permission for devices with those versions. And I believe you don't even have to ejecute `requestPermissions()` for the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission for devices < 12. You just have to `startDiscovery()`. The only one you need for devices on versions between 10 and 11 is `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, LOCATION is a "dangerous" permission so it require runtime permission,

BLUETOOTH_SCAN and other did not, so usually just requesting it will accept it automatically.

i found that information on multiple site, but still got issue hope it help you

EDIT:
after more search i found my solution:

https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/issues/246#issuecomment-1058869184

based on this comment, i understand that i must requestion FINE_LOCATION only(android 11) also in my manifest i must have both FINE and COARSE

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to change my "min Sdk version" to 23 in Android Studio, because to requestPermissions for "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" /> is minimum sdk version 23

Comment: I am not sure but I think this worked. So I had te duty to write this comment :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing in Android 10 & 11. Bluetooth SCAN & CONNECT permission is in this case always denied. Android IDE shows an error when you does not request this permission - just ignore this error (it is likely bug, you can successfuly compile the sources). In fact you should work in legacy mode & you really need only permissions (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) for 10 & 11. Do not request the permissions for COARSE and FINE at the same time. Anyway if you does not need fine location or RSSI, you should use those features to be able scan nearby devices... It is easier when devices can be bounded, but in my case I had BLE device HM-10.